# Call Service In Function In config() In AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, restangular, angular-local-storage

I have this config() block in an AngularJS app:

```
  .config(function(RestangularProvider, apiServerConstants) {
    RestangularProvider.setBaseUrl(apiServerConstants.url + apiServerConstants.apiPath + apiServerConstants.apiVersion);
    RestangularProvider.setFullRequestInterceptor(function(element, operation, route, url, headers, params, httpConfig) {
      // access local storage
      return {
        element: element,
        params: _.extend(params, {single: true}),
        headers: headers,
        httpConfig: httpConfig
      };
    });
  });
```

How do I inject my localStorageService (from grevory/angular-local-storage) in the function being called by `RestangularProvider.setFullRequestInterceptor()`. I need to configure the interceptor function such that it calls `localStorageService.get()` to be able to access data in local storage to include with every Restangular request I make.

PS: I know that in config() or run(), you can only call providers or constants. I'm wondering if the code in the function inside setFullRequestInterceptor(), which only gets called at run-time, can somehow instantiate or get localStorageService?

Answer (score 1):

**This not possible.**

You can only inject into `.config` the following items:

- CONSTANT
- VALUE
- PROVIDER

See oficial doc [here](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/module), I quote :

> Configuration blocks - get executed during the provider registrations
>   and configuration phase. Only providers and constants can be injected
>   into configuration blocks. This is to prevent accidental instantiation
>   of services before they have been fully configured.

Comment: The function setup inside setFullRequestInterceptor() gets called only at run-time. Is there not a way to setup the code inside that function to instantiate/new/call localStorageService then?